# Array elements are skipped

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to move the joints of my robot at 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees, but it only displays the state of 90 and 270 degrees on gazebo repeatedly. I output the results to the terminal, and actually four angles show periodically, and counts are formally 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.... However I do the different tests, the robot always skips one element between two array elements on gazebo. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Here is my plugin code.

```
#include <functional>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/common.hh>
#include <ignition/math/Vector3.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

namespace gazebo
{
  int count = 0;
  float pos[4] = {0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71};

  class ModelPush : public ModelPlugin
  {
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {
      this->model = _parent;
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(std::bind(&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this));
    }

    public: void OnUpdate()
    {
       this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->SetPosition(0, pos[count%4]);
       this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->>Update();
       this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->SetPosition(0, pos[count%4]);
       this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->>Update();

       cout << fixed << this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->GetAngle(0).Radian() << "\t";
       cout << fixed << this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->GetAngle(0).Radian() << "\t" << count << endl;

       count++;
       usleep(500000);
    }

    private: physics::ModelPtr model;
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
  };
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(ModelPush)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20124/array-elements-are-skipped/) by [jwchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5575/jwchang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looking at the `OnUpdate()` method in your code...

```
public: void OnUpdate()
{
  this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->SetPosition(0, pos[count%4]);
  this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->>Update();
  this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->SetPosition(0, pos[count%4]);
  this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->>Update();

  cout << fixed << this->model->GetJoint("joint1")->GetAngle(0).Radian() << "\t";
  cout << fixed << this->model->GetJoint("joint2")->GetAngle(0).Radian() << "\t" << count << endl;

  count++;
  usleep(500000);
}
```

---

1. 

You are sleeping for 0.5s inside this callback method which is connected to the world update event
(`this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(std::bind(&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this));`)

Note that, according to [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15372/plugin-order-of-execution/), `OnUpdate()`is blocking the entire physics thread.

Thus, instead of ~1000 iterations a second, you are looking at ~1 iteration every 2 seconds and whatever wonky behavior comes with that.

**Solution:**
Instead of sleeping inside `OnUpdate()`, use `this->world->GetSimTime().Double()` to check the elapsed simulated since the last `count` increment. See [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9373/getting-simulation-time-from-visual-plugin/?answer=9582#post-id-9582) and [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2268/querying-simulation-time-in-a-plugin/?answer=2322#post-id-2322).

---

2. 

I'm not a fan of using `SetPosition()`. If I remember correctly, `SetPosition()` moves everything to the desired position in a single time step and leaves the physics engine to clean up the mess caused by things magically teleporting.

**Solution:**
Check out `SetForce()` with a PID controller as explained in [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12366/clarification-on-moving-joint-with-model-plugin/) and [this answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2341/set-and-get-position-of-gazebo-model-using-ros-plugin/?answer=2363#post-id-2363).

---

3. 

Just a musing, but depending on your system's physical properties, 0.5s may not be enough time to move between positions in a "friendly" manner.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1